# ウェーブレット変換とフーリエ変換の計算量

Tags: アルゴリズム, 計算量

離散ウェーブレット変換の計算量はO(N)で、高速フーリエ変換の場合はO(N log N)になるそうですが

離散ウェーブレット変換の式も Σ(シグマ記号:summation)が２つのため二重ループになり
O(N^2)になると思うのですが、なぜ、O(N)になるのですか？

Comment: 「離散ウェーブレット変換の式も Σ(シグマ記号:summation)が２つ」はどの式を指していますか？（もし多重解像度解析のDWT定義をさすのなら、そもそも対象が2次元データなのでΣ2つはO(N)に相当します）